# So Ive been trying to solve the infamous 'question 6'

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

so I've set myself this question as a challenge and because of that do not want to read any solutions on the internet, so it would be appreciated if no one spoiled the answer, please just tell me if I'm incorrect

the question goes:
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$
prove that the expression above is equal to the square of an integer if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Now, I've been able to prove that when $b = a^3$, the expression will equal $a^2$, but am I mistaken to believe that the expression has many different sets of numbers that will satisfy the question?

In that case, is this a proper solution or is there another one that can somehow describe all sets at once?

I haven't looked at any solutions on the internet as I don't want to ruin the challenge for myself.

Comment: False assertions are typically harder to prove than true assertions.  Counter example, $a=1, b=2.$  Are you sure that you have specified the question correctly.  Could the question actually be: Identify all possible ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that the expression is a perfect square?

Comment: You said you set this question to yourself, but I haven't been able to find one where it is actually the square of a integer except for 1,1. What made you think it held in general?

Comment: The correct formulation is to prove that when that expression is an integer, it is a perfect square. For natural $a,b$, of course. It is a classic, well-known IMO problem.

Comment: verbatim, the question was "Let a and b be positive integers such that ab + 1 divides a^2 + b^2. Show that a^2 + b^2 / ab + 1 is the square of an integer."

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, if you knew all along (verbatim) what the question actually was, why did you withhold this information from your query?

Comment: idk i guess i thought it was too verbose? ill do that next time

Answer (score 1):

(Possibly too big) hint: Fix an integer $k$, for which there is a solution to $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=k$. Let $a$ be unknown and see that there are two solutions with the same $b$ and $k$.

This forms a single link in a chain of solutions. Study this chain, and you have solved the problem.

Comment: my question is more, 'is finding one set that satisfies the question an answer or is there another set that contains all sets that satisfy the answer'

Comment: @IDEFK The question is "prove that every single solution satisfies a certain requirement". You have found some solutions and they satisfy the requirement. You have to ask whether this is enough? The answer is no.